# PORO outside of MVC model needs user IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a bit new to Rails and I'm used to POROs within an MVC model. However this one project I am working on has a PORO that exists outside of the MVC directories.

```
App
  -Controller
  -Model
  -View
  -Serializer
  -PORO
  -Helpers
  -Etc
```

A module within the PORO directory needs the users IP address in order to perform an action. Since it doesn't exist within the MVC, there is no access to simple actions like request.remote_ip. Anyone have any idea how I can get the user ip without passing the value all the way down the line? It is included in the Serializer objects so doing so would mean I would have to pass the IP down the line in the serializers and then into the PORO module.

Thanks all!

Comment: The best way is to pass it down -- it's clean, easy to test and makes your intent obvious. There is a creaky gem, sentient_user https://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user that you could attempt to use, or least look to for an example of how to get the current user information outside of a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just pass it down.

Although you have different modules and folders for POROs and models they're essentially the same thing. The only difference (I assume) is that you models are ActiveRecords and therefore persisted to the database. I worked on plenty of Rails apps in which PORO and models are used in a very similar way and the only difference was the persistence. And how would you get the ip addresse into a model? You would also pass it in because you can't store the whole request.

For example

```rb
class Location
  def initialize(ip)
    @ip = ip
  end

  def city
    # todo
  end

  def country
    # todo
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @location = Location.new(request.ip)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass this directly to the PORO module? It is intertwined with various other serializers and I don't want to pass it to each serializer.